# How to create a range slider with thumb as png image in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, flutter-canvas

How to create smiley range slider in flutter. Like below GIF image. [image]

Discrete with Custom Theme I try to change thumb shape. But I want to change thumb as image.

```js
// Copyright 2015 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SliderDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = '/material/slider';

  @override
  _SliderDemoState createState() => new _SliderDemoState();
}

Path _triangle(double size, Offset thumbCenter, {bool invert = false}) {
  final Path thumbPath = new Path();
  final double height = math.sqrt(3.0) / 2.0;
  final double halfSide = size / 2.0;
  final double centerHeight = size * height / 3.0;
  final double sign = invert ? -1.0 : 1.0;
  thumbPath.moveTo(thumbCenter.dx - halfSide, thumbCenter.dy + sign * centerHeight);
  thumbPath.lineTo(thumbCenter.dx, thumbCenter.dy - 2.0 * sign * centerHeight);
  thumbPath.lineTo(thumbCenter.dx + halfSide, thumbCenter.dy + sign * centerHeight);
  thumbPath.close();
  return thumbPath;
}

class _CustomThumbShape extends SliderComponentShape {
  static const double _thumbSize = 4.0;
  static const double _disabledThumbSize = 5.0;

  @override
  Size getPreferredSize(bool isEnabled, bool isDiscrete) {
    return isEnabled ? const Size.fromRadius(_thumbSize) : const Size.fromRadius(_disabledThumbSize);
  }

  static final Tween<double> sizeTween = new Tween<double>(
    begin: _disabledThumbSize,
    end: _thumbSize,
  );

  @override
  void paint(
    PaintingContext context,
    Offset thumbCenter, {
    Animation<double> activationAnimation,
    Animation<double> enableAnimation,
    bool isDiscrete,
    TextPainter labelPainter,
    RenderBox parentBox,
    SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    TextDirection textDirection,
    double value,
  }) {
    final Canvas canvas = context.canvas;
    final ColorTween colorTween = new ColorTween(
      begin: sliderTheme.disabledThumbColor,
      end: sliderTheme.thumbColor,
    );
    final double size = _thumbSize * sizeTween.evaluate(enableAnimation);
    final Path thumbPath = _triangle(size, thumbCenter);
    canvas.drawPath(thumbPath, new Paint()..color = colorTween.evaluate(enableAnimation));
  }
}

class _CustomValueIndicatorShape extends SliderComponentShape {
  static const double _indicatorSize = 4.0;
  static const double _disabledIndicatorSize = 3.0;
  static const double _slideUpHeight = 40.0;

  @override
  Size getPreferredSize(bool isEnabled, bool isDiscrete) {
    return new Size.fromRadius(isEnabled ? _indicatorSize : _disabledIndicatorSize);
  }

  static final Tween<double> sizeTween = new Tween<double>(
    begin: _disabledIndicatorSize,
    end: _indicatorSize,
  );

  @override
  void paint(
    PaintingContext context,
    Offset thumbCenter, {
    Animation<double> activationAnimation,
    Animation<double> enableAnimation,
    bool isDiscrete,
    TextPainter labelPainter,
    RenderBox parentBox,
    SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    TextDirection textDirection,
    double value,
  }) {
    final Canvas canvas = context.canvas;
    final ColorTween enableColor = new ColorTween(
      begin: sliderTheme.disabledThumbColor,
      end: sliderTheme.valueIndicatorColor,
    );
    final Tween<double> slideUpTween = new Tween<double>(
      begin: 0.0,
      end: _slideUpHeight,
    );
    final double size = _indicatorSize * sizeTween.evaluate(enableAnimation);
    final Offset slideUpOffset = new Offset(0.0, -slideUpTween.evaluate(activationAnimation));
    final Path thumbPath = _triangle(
      size,
      thumbCenter + slideUpOffset,
      invert: true,
    );
    final Color paintColor = enableColor.evaluate(enableAnimation).withAlpha((255.0 * activationAnimation.value).round());
    canvas.drawPath(
      thumbPath,
      new Paint()..color = paintColor,
    );
    canvas.drawLine(
        thumbCenter,
        thumbCenter + slideUpOffset,
        new Paint()
          ..color = paintColor
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
          ..strokeWidth = 2.0);
    labelPainter.paint(canvas, thumbCenter + slideUpOffset + new Offset(-labelPainter.width / 2.0, -labelPainter.height - 4.0));
  }
}

class _SliderDemoState extends State<SliderDemo> {
  double _value = 25.0;
  double _discreteValue = 20.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: const Text('Sliders')),
      body: new Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0),
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Slider(
                  value: _value,
                  min: 0.0,
                  max: 100.0,
                  onChanged: (double value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _value = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                const Text('Continuous'),
              ],
            ),
            new Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: const <Widget>[
                const Slider(value: 0.25, onChanged: null),
                const Text('Disabled'),
              ],
            ),
            new Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Slider(
                  value: _discreteValue,
                  min: 0.0,
                  max: 200.0,
                  divisions: 5,
                  label: '${_discreteValue.round()}',
                  onChanged: (double value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _discreteValue = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                const Text('Discrete'),
              ],
            ),
            new Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                new SliderTheme(
                  data: theme.sliderTheme.copyWith(
                    activeTrackColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                    inactiveTrackColor: Colors.black26,
                    activeTickMarkColor: Colors.white70,
                    inactiveTickMarkColor: Colors.black,
                    overlayColor: Colors.black12,
                    thumbColor: Colors.red,
                    valueIndicatorColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                    thumbShape: new _CustomThumbShape(),
                    valueIndicatorShape: new _CustomValueIndicatorShape(),
                    valueIndicatorTextStyle: theme.accentTextTheme.body2.copyWith(color: Colors.black87),
                  ),
                  child: new Slider(
                    value: _discreteValue,
                    min: 0.0,
                    max: 10.0,
                    divisions: 5,
                    //semanticFormatterCallback: (double value) => value.round().toString(),
                    label: '${_discreteValue.round()}',
                    onChanged: (double value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _discreteValue = value;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                const Text('Discrete with Custom Theme'),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include what you've tried already, and what the specific difficulties are that you've been having rather than asking for a full complete solution. See [the SO how to ask...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  But due to the very complicated nature of what you're looking to build, you're almost for sure going to need to use CustomPainters (at least for the dynamically changing face), along with probably a GestureDetector (you might be able to use drag/drop but it's going to get difficult quickly).

Comment: @ rmtmckenzie I want to change thumb as image not an shapes like circle,triangle

Answer (score 25):

You need to create custom slider.

Let’s split tasks:

Gestures:

- Tap, when user taps on the one of the labels.
- Drag, when user drags the indicator.

Animations:

- Background animations

  - moving text
  - scaling head
- Switcher animations:

  - color
  - face

Extra:
  - Need to think what to do when user stop drugging between two labels.

**After 15 hours of thinking and coding, I have:**

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math.dart' as v_math;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('How was the help you recived?', style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF6f7478), fontSize: 18),),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              ReviewSlider()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ReviewSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ReviewSliderState createState() => _ReviewSliderState();
}

class _ReviewSliderState extends State<ReviewSlider> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  double intitalReviewValue = 2;
  final List<String> reviews = ['Terrible', 'Bad', 'Okay', 'Good', 'Great'];

  Animation<double> _animation;
  AnimationController _controller;
  Tween<double> _tween;
  double _innerWidth;
  double _animationValue;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = AnimationController(
      value: intitalReviewValue,
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    );
    _tween = Tween(end: intitalReviewValue);
    _animation = _tween.animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        curve: Curves.easeIn,
        parent: _controller,
      ),
    )..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          _animationValue = _animation.value;
        });
      });
    _animationValue = intitalReviewValue;
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_afterLayout);
  }

  _afterLayout(_) {
    setState(() {
      _innerWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 2 * paddingSize;
    });
  }

  void handleTap(int state) {
    _controller.duration = Duration(milliseconds: 400);

    _tween.begin = _tween.end;
    _tween.end = state.toDouble();
    _controller.reset();
    _controller.forward();
  }

  _onDrag(details) {
    var newAnimatedValue = _calcAnimatedValueFormDragX(
      details.globalPosition.dx,
    );
    if (newAnimatedValue > 0 && newAnimatedValue < reviews.length - 1) {
      setState(
        () {
          _animationValue = newAnimatedValue;
        },
      );
    }
  }

  _calcAnimatedValueFormDragX(x) {
    return (x - circleDiameter / 2 - paddingSize * 2) / _innerWidth * reviews.length;
  }

  _onDragEnd(_) {
    _controller.duration = Duration(milliseconds: 100);
    _tween.begin = _animationValue;
    _tween.end = _animationValue.round().toDouble();
    _controller.reset();
    _controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: _innerWidth == null
          ? Container()
          : Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: paddingSize),
              height: 200,
              child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                MeasureLine(
                  states: reviews,
                  handleTap: handleTap,
                  animationValue: _animationValue,
                  width: _innerWidth,
                ),
                MyIndicator(
                  animationValue: _animationValue,
                  width: _innerWidth,
                  onDrag: _onDrag,
                  onDragEnd: _onDragEnd,
                ),
                Text(_animationValue.round().toString()),
              ]),
            ),
    );
  }
}

const double circleDiameter = 60;
const double paddingSize = 10;

class MeasureLine extends StatelessWidget {
  MeasureLine({this.handleTap, this.animationValue, this.states, this.width});

  final double animationValue;
  final Function handleTap;
  final List<String> states;
  final double width;

  List<Widget> _buildUnits() {
    var res = <Widget>[];
    var animatingUnitIndex = animationValue.round();
    var unitAnimatingValue = (animationValue * 10 % 10 / 10 - 0.5).abs() * 2;

    states.asMap().forEach((index, text) {
      var paddingTop = 0.0;
      var scale = 0.7;
      var opacity = .3;
      if (animatingUnitIndex == index) {
        paddingTop = unitAnimatingValue * 5;
        scale = (1 - unitAnimatingValue) * 0.7;
        opacity = 0.3 + unitAnimatingValue * 0.7;
      }
      res.add(LimitedBox(
        key: ValueKey(text),
        maxWidth: circleDiameter,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            handleTap(index);
          },
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Transform.scale(
                  scale: scale,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Head(),
                      Face(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        animationValue: index.toDouble(),
                      )
                    ],
                  )),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: paddingTop),
                child: Opacity(
                  opacity: opacity,
                  child: Text(
                    text,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ));
    });
    return res;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Positioned(
          top: circleDiameter / 2,
          left: 20,
          width: width - 40,
          child: Container(
            width: width,
            color: Color(0xFFeceeef),
            height: 3,
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: _buildUnits(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Face extends StatelessWidget {
  Face({
    this.color = const Color(0xFF616154),
    this.animationValue,
  });

  final Color color;
  final double animationValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: circleDiameter,
      width: circleDiameter,
      child: CustomPaint(
        size: Size(300, 300),
        painter: MyPainter(animationValue, color: color),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  MyPainter(
    animationValue, {
    this.color = const Color(0xFF615f56),
  })  : activeIndex = animationValue.floor(),
        unitAnimatingValue = (animationValue * 10 % 10 / 10);

  Color color;
  final int activeIndex;
  final double unitAnimatingValue;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    _drawEye(canvas, size);
    _drawMouth(canvas, size);
  }

  _drawEye(canvas, size) {
    var angle = 0.0;
    var wide = 0.0;

    switch (activeIndex) {
      case 0:
        angle = 55 - unitAnimatingValue * 50;
        wide = 80.0;
        break;
      case 1:
        wide = 80 - unitAnimatingValue * 80;
        angle = 5;
        break;
    }
    var degree1 = 90 * 3 + angle;
    var degree2 = 90 * 3 - angle + wide;
    var x1 = size.width / 2 * 0.65;
    var x2 = size.width - x1;
    var y = size.height * 0.41;
    var eyeRadius = 5.0;

    var paint = Paint()..color = color;
    canvas.drawArc(
      Rect.fromCircle(
        center: Offset(x1, y),
        radius: eyeRadius,
      ),
      v_math.radians(degree1),
      v_math.radians(360 - wide),
      false,
      paint,
    );
    canvas.drawArc(
      Rect.fromCircle(
        center: Offset(x2, y),
        radius: eyeRadius,
      ),
      v_math.radians(degree2),
      v_math.radians(360 - wide),
      false,
      paint,
    );
  }

  _drawMouth(Canvas canvas, size) {
    var upperY = size.height * 0.70;
    var lowerY = size.height * 0.77;
    var middleY = (lowerY - upperY) / 2 + upperY;

    var leftX = size.width / 2 * 0.65;
    var rightX = size.width - leftX;
    var middleX = size.width / 2;

    double y1, y3, x2, y2;
    Path path2;
    switch (activeIndex) {
      case 0:
        y1 = lowerY;
        x2 = middleX;
        y2 = upperY;
        y3 = lowerY;
        break;
      case 1:
        y1 = lowerY;
        x2 = middleX;
        y2 = unitAnimatingValue * (middleY - upperY) + upperY;
        y3 = lowerY - unitAnimatingValue * (lowerY - upperY);
        break;
      case 2:
        y1 = unitAnimatingValue * (upperY - lowerY) + lowerY;
        x2 = middleX;
        y2 = unitAnimatingValue * (lowerY + 3 - middleY) + middleY;
        y3 = upperY;
        break;
      case 3:
        y1 = upperY;
        x2 = middleX;
        y2 = lowerY + 3;
        y3 = upperY;
        path2 = Path()
          ..moveTo(leftX, y1)
          ..quadraticBezierTo(
            x2,
            y2,
            upperY - 2.5,
            y3 - 2.5,
          )
          ..quadraticBezierTo(
            x2,
            y2 - unitAnimatingValue * (y2 - upperY + 2.5),
            leftX,
            upperY - 2.5,
          )
          ..close();
        break;
      case 4:
        y1 = upperY;
        x2 = middleX;
        y2 = lowerY + 3;
        y3 = upperY;
        path2 = Path()
          ..moveTo(leftX, y1)
          ..quadraticBezierTo(
            x2,
            y2,
            upperY - 2.5,
            y3 - 2.5,
          )
          ..quadraticBezierTo(
            x2,
            upperY - 2.5,
            leftX,
            upperY - 2.5,
          )
          ..close();
        break;
    }
    var path = Path()
      ..moveTo(leftX, y1)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(
        x2,
        y2,
        rightX,
        y3,
      );

    canvas.drawPath(
        path,
        Paint()
          ..color = color
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
          ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
          ..strokeWidth = 5);

    if (path2 != null) {
      canvas.drawPath(
        path2,
        Paint()
          ..color = color
          ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
          ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(MyPainter oldDelegate) {
    return unitAnimatingValue != oldDelegate.unitAnimatingValue ||
        activeIndex != oldDelegate.activeIndex;
  }
}

class MyIndicator extends StatelessWidget {
  MyIndicator({
    this.animationValue,
    width,
    this.onDrag,
    this.onDragStart,
    this.onDragEnd,
  })  : width = width - circleDiameter,
        possition = animationValue == 0 ? 0 : animationValue / 4;

  final double possition;
  final Function onDrag;
  final Function onDragStart;
  final Function onDragEnd;
  final double width;
  final double animationValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Positioned(
        top: 0,
        left: width * possition,
        child: _buildIndicator(),
      ),
    );
  }

  _buildIndicator() {
    var opacityOfYellow = possition > 0.5 ? 1.0 : possition * 2;
    return GestureDetector(
      onPanDown: onDragStart,
      onPanUpdate: onDrag,
      onPanStart: onDrag,
      onPanEnd: onDragEnd,
      child: Container(
        width: circleDiameter,
        height: circleDiameter,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Head(
              color: Color(0xFFf4b897),
              hasShadow: true,
            ),
            Opacity(
              opacity: opacityOfYellow,
              child: Head(
                color: Color(0xFFfee385),
              ),
            ),
            Face(
              animationValue: animationValue,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Head extends StatelessWidget {
  Head({this.color = const Color(0xFFc9ced2), this.hasShadow = false});

  final Color color;
  final bool hasShadow;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: circleDiameter,
      width: circleDiameter,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        boxShadow: hasShadow
            ? [BoxShadow(color: Colors.black26, offset: Offset(0, 2), blurRadius: 5.0)]
            : null,
        color: color,
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

https://github.com/kherel/review_slider