# Can Flutter drag and drop have a dynamic endpoint? or just a predefined targets?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I want to create a drag and drop app, but all of the examples I see have the drop being a predefined target. Is it possible and would I implement a drag and then drop anywhere I release my finger with the same properties and data transfer methods attached ?

I have looked at multiple examples and tutorials and the docs seem cryptic or I missed something for sure

Comment: Maybe I could help you with it, if you give more information what you are willing to build.

Comment: check this example of using gesture detector https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185894/how-to-create-a-range-slider-with-thumb-as-png-image-in-flutter/57826401#57826401

Comment: Hi and thank you . Is there a way I can direct message you. Are you interested in working on a project together ?

Comment: Sure, my email is kherel@gmail.com..

Comment: Here is a solution using Positioned() and RenderBox sizing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57080144/how-to-move-element-anywhere-inside-parent-container-with-drag-and-drop-in-flutt/58682175#58682175

Answer (score 0):

You can use gesture detector it has several properties:
onPanEnd, onPanStart, onPanUpdate
+ vertical and horizontal drag properties

From these you can get details of local or global points of touch, and build your own logic on it data.